# how to limit appending json objects in python

Tags: python, json, append

I want to only add 10 objects to my json array when I append, but in this current method I end up appending all key/values that match.

Is there a graceful way to limit only 10 objects being appended inside the for loop?

```
for i in jsonData['data']:
            response.append({'lat': i['lat'], 'long' : i['long']})
            json.dumps(response)
```

Comment: How about `if`?

Comment: Tried this: `for i in jsonData['data'][:10]: ...` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the data is a list, you can slice:

```
for i in jsonData['data'][:10]:
    response.append({'lat': i['lat'], 'long' : i['long']})
    json.dumps(response)
```

Otherwise, `break` at the count of 10:

```
for i, v in enumerate(jsonData['data']):
    if i == 10:
        break
    response.append({'lat': v['lat'], 'long' : v['long']})
    json.dumps(response)
```

Comment: Awesome, and very clean! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to `json.dumps` all intermediate stages, then this should do:

```
response = [{'lat': i['lat'], 'long' : i['long']} for i in jsonData['data'][:10]]
```